# Scrappy not Scraping out data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wrote the following script to scrape data from [this site](https://www.freelancer.in/jobs/python_web-scraping_web-crawling/):

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobs'
    start_urls = ['https://www.freelancer.in/jobs/python_web-scraping_web-crawling/']

    def parse(self, response):

        for title in response.xpath('//div[@class = "JobSearchCard-primary-heading"]//a'):
            yield{
                'title' : title.xpath('a/text()').extract_first()
            }
```

However, when I run it I only receive an empty file except for the title? Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath selector return `None`. It probably should be:

`'title' : title.xpath('text()').extract_first()`

Furthermore, you can strip excessive symbols:

`'title' : title.xpath('text()').extract_first(default='').strip()`

`default=''` intended to avoid exception if selector found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot and tell me you didn't get your expected titles from that page. Your defined xpath was faulty. Moreover, there are huge whitespaces in each string so you need to `.strip()` them as well. The below script will give you the clean output.

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobs'
    start_urls = ['https://www.freelancer.in/jobs/python_web-scraping_web-crawling/']

    def parse(self, response):

        for title in response.xpath('//*[@class="JobSearchCard-primary-heading-link"]/text()').extract():
            yield{
                'title' : title.strip()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobs'
    start_urls = ['https://www.freelancer.in/jobs/python_web-scraping_web-crawling/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.xpath('//div[@class = "JobSearchCard-primary-heading"]//a'):
            yield {
                'title' : title.xpath('./text()').extract_first().strip()
            }
```

the inner xpath should be relative to the loop's node.